# Saving and restoring Canvas->Pen State

Tags: c++builder

I am trying to save the current state of Canvas->Pen then restoring it but it does not work and all GDI functions use the new pen after restoring

```
    TPen * OldPen, * newpen;
    OldPen = Canvas->Pen;
    newpen = new TPen;
    newpen->Color = clPurple;
    newpen->Width = 2;
    Canvas->Pen = newpen;
// draw with the new pen...
    Canvas->Pen = OldPen;
    delete newpen;
```

The Oldpen is never restored, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You are not actually saving and restoring anything.

You are merely saving a *pointer* to the internal `TPen` object that the `Canvas` owns.  When you then assign a new `TPen` object to the `Canvas->Pen` property, you are not swapping objects at all, you are simply copying the property values from the `newpen` object to the `Canvas->Pen` object - the same object that `oldpen` is pointing at.  When you then try to "restore" `oldpen`, you are simply copying property values from the original (modified) `TPen` back to itself, which is a no-op.

To do what you are attempting, you need to make a copy of the `Canvas->Pen` object, and then copy it back, like this:

```
TPen *OldPen = new TPen;
OldPen->Assign(Canvas->Pen);
Canvas->Pen->Color = clPurple;
Canvas->Pen->Width = 2;
// draw with the new pen...
Canvas->Pen->Assign(OldPen);
delete OldPen;
```

Alternatively, use GDI's own built-in [save + restore functionality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdi/saving--restoring--and-resetting-a-device-context) instead:

```
int oldstate = ::SaveDC(Canvas->Handle);
Canvas->Pen->Color = clPurple;
Canvas->Pen->Width = 2;
// draw with the new pen...
::RestoreDC(Canvas->Handle, oldstate);
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifications and solution, I will use 2nd option

Comment: 2nd option SaveDC / RestoreDC does not work, 1st one does